# Recursive/Strong Induction

Tags: induction

Suppose that $a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots$ is a sequence defined as follows. 
$$a_0 = 2, a_1 = 4, a_2 = 6 \text{, and } a_k = 7 a_{k-3} \text{ for all integers $k \ge 3$.}$$
Prove that $a_n$ is even for all integers $n \ge 0$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Well I have no idea how to prove it, I know how to prove the base case and write the inductive step but not applying inductive hypothesis and proving it's even!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except the basic case is trivial and assuming that the statement holds for each $k \leq n - 1$ you have $a_n = 7a_{n-3} $. By hypothesis $a_{k-3} = 2\gamma$, $\gamma$ integer, so $a_n = 14 \gamma$ which implies that 2 divides $a_n $.

Comment: what about 'k+1'th term of a?How can we prove it's also divisible!Or Do I really have to prove that too :(

Comment: I made a mistake, the induction is basic case and assuming that it holds up to n -1 then we prove the case n. Now since it is true up to n you could verify n + 1... but you don't need to do that because of the induction you just proved. About the divisibility... an integer is even if it is the product of 2 times another integer, and such property assuming it holds up to n -1 also hold to n as we proved.